# A better way to check for potion use?

Tags: python, loops

In my game, I came into a problem with potions. If there is to be a potion in a certain room I would create a new instance of my Potion() class like so:

```
potion = Potion()
```

The problem was that the user could call upon this as many times as they wanted and heal themselves until their health was maxed as the raw_input() was in an infinite loop. I solved this problem by using `del` to delete the instance.

My next problem was with rooms that contained more than one potion. This was my solution

```
potion = Potion()
potion_exist = True
potion2 = Potion()
potion2_exist = True
potion3 = Potion()
potion3_exist = True
```

And in the loop:

```
if next == "potion":
    if potion_exist:
        print "Potion 1"
        potion.heal(You)
        del potion
        potion_exist = False
    elif potion2_exist:
        print "Potion 2"
        potion2.heal(You)
        del potion2
        potion2_exist = False
    elif potion3_exist:
        print "Potion 3"
        potion3.heal(You)
        del potion3
        potion3_exist = False
    else:
        print "There is no potion to use."
```

This seems like a fairly long winded approach to me, but it works. I was just wondering if I was overlooking another simpler way to do this. If not, I'm ok with using this format, but if I could clean up my code I'd rather do that.
Thanks!

Comment: basic rule of thumb: any time you find yourself naming variables numerically/sequentially, you should be probably be using an array instead. and once you have an array, it's trivial to loop on that array and perform operations on every array item.

Comment: What you are doing is absolutely ugly. You want to use list where you have instances of potions and delete them when used using `pop` or similar list methods. I will write up some code and show what I mean.

Comment: Could you explain why you don't use list or set?

Answer (score 1):

Use list to store potion instances. Define it like this in your main function.

```
potions = []
for i in range(3):  # append 3 potions to the list
    potions.append(Potion())
```

The code in the loop will look something like this (it always uses the zeroth potion in the list):

```
if next == "potion":
    if (len(potions) > 0):  # if there are potions left
        print "potion"
        potions[0].heal(You)  # heal using zeroth potion from the list
        potions.pop(0)  # remove zeroth item from the list
```

Comment: thank you, this is a much better way of doing it. Not sure why I didn't even consider a list.